# Center inputs inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I give up, and have come here for help.

I'm trying to align the inside of this div so thats in the exact middle:

[image]

(The red borders are just so I can see the layout of each item...)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "Product Sans";
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: url("ProductSans-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

.form {
 background-color: grey;
 background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.7);
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font: 1em "Product Sans";
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.textInput {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.textInput:focus {
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
}

.textInput:invalid {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent;
}
.submit {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
 border: 1px solid red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
 border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Beautiful login - made with <3, PHP, CSS and HTML</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="form">
   <form action="/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your username here" required  />
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="passWord" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your password here" required />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" title="Click this button if you are sure your information is right" >Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <script>
   var screenWidth = $(window).width();
   var screenHeight = $(window).height();
   $(".form").css("width", screenWidth / 3);
   $(".form").css("height", screenHeight / 3 + 32);
   $(".textInput").css("width", screenWidth / 4)
   $(".submit").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
   var URL = "https://source.unsplash.com/" + screenWidth + "x" + screenHeight + "/?nature,water";
   $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + URL + ")");
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've managed to center the big, grey, round-cornered rectangle, but the same method didn't work for the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add these three properties to your `.form` class to achieve the vertical centering of the contents:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Product Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("ProductSans-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

.form {
  background-color: grey;
  background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: 1em "Product Sans";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.textInput {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.textInput:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
}

.textInput:invalid {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}

.submit {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Beautiful login - made with
    <3, PHP, CSS and HTML</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <form action="/index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="userName" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your username here" required />
      <br />
      <input type="password" name="passWord" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your password here" required />
      <br />
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" title="Click this button if you are sure your information is right">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    $(".form").css("width", screenWidth / 3);
    $(".form").css("height", screenHeight / 3 + 32);
    $(".textInput").css("width", screenWidth / 4)
    $(".submit").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
    var URL = "https://source.unsplash.com/" + screenWidth + "x" + screenHeight + "/?nature,water";
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + URL + ")");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want your input text content to be center then simply use css  `text-align:center`

```
 .textInput {
   text-align:center
 }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "Product Sans";
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: url("ProductSans-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

.form {
 background-color: grey;
 background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.7);
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font: 1em "Product Sans";
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.textInput {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
}

.textInput:focus {
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
}

.textInput:invalid {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent;
}
.submit {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
 border: 1px solid red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 138, 128, 0.7);
 border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Beautiful login - made with <3, PHP, CSS and HTML</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="form">
   <form action="/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your username here" required  />
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="passWord" class="textInput" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your password here" required />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" title="Click this button if you are sure your information is right" >Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <script>
   var screenWidth = $(window).width();
   var screenHeight = $(window).height();
   $(".form").css("width", screenWidth / 3);
   $(".form").css("height", screenHeight / 3 + 32);
   $(".textInput").css("width", screenWidth / 4)
   $(".submit").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
   var URL = "https://source.unsplash.com/" + screenWidth + "x" + screenHeight + "/?nature,water";
   $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + URL + ")");
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will align the text in the input itself

Comment: Worked perfectly, I'll mark as an answer when the time limit has depleted :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not really applying your method to the contents :). You can center them the exact same way you center the outer `.form` div. Adding this to your CSS should work:

```
form {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the contents vertically and horizontally center give these styles to the form:

```
.form{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-contents: center;
}
```

And to place the whole form in the middle of the page, without absolutely positioning the form and giving top:50%, wrap it inside a container with height 100vh, for example:

```
.container{
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```